# Can't add Image http.post POST 500 internal server error. AngularJS Java Spring

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I have a problem with adding Image. When I press button i got error "POST http://localhost:8080/image/addImage 500 (Internal Server Error)". I think with my controller and class everything is okey but I know only basic in angularJS. I can't find good resolve for me on google well I'm writing here. Thanks for help!

JS

```
var ImageController = function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {

$scope.name = $routeParams.name;

$scope.url = "i.imgur.com/" + $scope.name;


$scope.image = {};


$scope.addNewImage = function(image) {

    $http.post('image/addImage', image).success(function() {
        $scope.image.name = '';
    })
};}
```

Contoller

```
@RequestMapping("/image")
@Controller
public class ImageController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/addImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void addImage(@RequestBody Image image) {imageService.addImage(image); }
```

Image class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IMAGE")
public class Image {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;


@NotEmpty
@Column(name="URL", nullable=false)
private String url;


public Image(Long id, String url) {
    this.id = id;
    this.url = url;
}
```

HTML
http://pastebin.com/73MExyJ8

Comment: With "500 (Internal Server Error)" you should find some error (probably a Java stack trace) in your server log.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you answer David, I don't have any stack trace in Java. I check database and i don't have any new records. Maybe my code with saving object to database isn't correct.

```
public interface ImageService {
 public void addImage(Image image);}
```

Implements

```
@Service("imageService")
public class ImageServiceImpl implements ImageService {
@Override
public void addImage(Image image)
{

    HibernateUtil hibernateUtil = new HibernateUtil();
    SessionFactory sessFact = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessFact.getCurrentSession();
    org.hibernate.Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();

    System.out.println(tr.isActive());

    session.save(image);

    tr.commit();
}}
```